# How do you pass a mocked class to an extended class's parent constructor in Scala?

Tags: java, scala, mockito

I have to add some functionality to some existing code that's set up like

```
    class A(foo: Foo, bar: Bar) {
        // stuff
        def aMethod(){
            // some setup
            bMethod()
        }

        private def bMethod() {
            // do some stuff
        }
    }

    class ATest() {
        val mockA = new ExtendsA(instance, foo, bar)
        val results = mockA.aMethod()
        // validate some stuff
    }
    class ExtendsA(instance: Instance, foo: Foo, bar: Bar) extends A(foo: Foo, bar: Bar) {
        // override some stuff
    }
```

I added some functionality that has to get executed during bMethod(). This requires access to data that's not controlled by our code and that can't be properly setup during debug, so it's placed into a new class and mocked.

```
    class MoreFunctionality() {}

    class A(foo: Foo, bar: Bar, moreFunctionality : MoreFunctionality = new MoreFunctionality()) {
        // stuff
        def aMethod(){
            // some setup
            bMethod()
        }

        private def bMethod() {
            moreFunctionality.doNewStuff()
            // do some stuff

        }
    }

    class ATest() {
        val mockMoreFunctionality = mock[MoreFunctionality]
        doNothing().when(mockMoreFunctionality).doNewStuff()
        val mockA = new ExtendsA(instance, foo, bar, mockMoreFunctionality)
        val results = mockA.aMethod()
        // validate some stuff
    }
    class ExtendsA(instance: Instance, foo: Foo, bar: Bar, mockMoreFunctionality: MoreFunctionality) extends A(foo, bar, mockMoreFunctionality) {
        // override some stuff
    }
```

The problem that I'm running into is that everything I seem to try ignores the fact that the MoreFunctionality class has been mocked and attempts to use the actual method. I've tested that the instance is actually a mock using mockingDetails(obj).isMock() and it is.

I've also tried rearranging it so the method itself accepts the new class as a parameter which also didn't work.

```
    class MoreFunctionality() {}

    class A(foo: Foo, bar: Bar) {
        // stuff
        def aMethod(moreFunctionality: MoreFunctionality){
            // some setup
            bMethod(moreFunctionality)
        }

        private def bMethod(moreFunctionality: MoreFunctionality) {
            moreFunctionality.doNewStuff()
            // do some stuff

        }
    }

    class ATest() {
        val mockMoreFunctionality = mock[MoreFunctionality]
        doNothing().when(mockMoreFunctionality).doNewStuff()
        val mockA = new ExtendsA(instance, foo, bar)
        val results = mockA.aMethod(mockMoreFunctionality)
        // validate some stuff
    }
    class ExtendsA(instance: Instance, foo: Foo, bar: Bar) extends A(foo, bar) 
    {
        // override some stuff
    }
```

Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: Does the real method for `doNewStuff` take any params? if so, how are you stubbing it? Also, you shouldn't have to use `doNothing` on a mock, mocks do nothing by default, that code is to override behaviour on spys

Comment: So, we ended up figuring it out. The issue is that the class that extends A takes an instance of class A as a parameter. That instance is a mock instance and the method used is being called from there. So, when we added mockMoreFunctionality as part of ExtendsA, the tests were using the non mocked value from the mock of A.

It's all terribly confusing and very likely not well designed, but we had to make our additions work with what was there.